# Why don't these variables work?

Tags: python, function, variables

I'm a real newbie to programming. I've been going through "Learn Python the Hard Way" and it's really great. I've now gone and tried to make a little script on my own similar to the one in the 19th exercise, just to practice. Practicing different ways of running a function.

The following variables do not seem to work though:

```
beerseach = totalbeers / guests
spiritseach = totalspirits / guests

party(beerseach, spiritseach)
```

I get the error "unsupported operand type(s) for : 'int' and 'str'".

I've put the rest of the code below if the problem is in the context.

```
def party(beer, spirits):
    print "We have %s beers" % beer
    print "We have %s bottles of spirits" % spirits
    print "Is it enough? We'll find out tonight\n"

beers = 450
spiritbottles = 40

totalbeers = 546 + 124
totalspirits = beers / spiritbottles

beeramount = raw_input("How many beers are you bringing? ")
spiritamount = raw_input("How many spirits are you bringing? ")
#guests = raw_input("How many guests are coming? ")

party(500, 50)

party(beers, spiritbottles)

party(totalbeers, totalspirits)

party(beeramount, spiritamount)

party(beers + 49, spiritbottles - 21)

#party(guests + beers, guests + totalspirits) apparently cannot do this with int objects/variables/whatever

print 20 * 450
print beeramount * totalspirits

raw_input("Now we move on. Press enter.")

guests = raw_input("How many guests are coming? ")
print "We're going to have to work out how many beers each person can have"

beerseach = totalbeers / guests
spiritseach = totalspirits / guests
                                    #WHY DOESN'T THIS WORK????!
party(beerseach, spiritseach)
```

Comment: Or any one of the hundreds of other questions you'd find if you Googled the error message

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You get the `guests` variable as

```
guests = raw_input("How many guests are coming? ")
```

The return from `raw_input` is a `str`. You have to convert it to an `int`

```
guests = int(raw_input("How many guests are coming? "))
```

Comment: Thank you, that's very helpful for my learning!